# Is it possible to select cells in the second column of an HTML table and move them to the bottom of the first column using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please forgive my inexperience with programming -- I will try to be as articulate as possible. If I've not been specific enough or I'm missing something else, please let me know.

I am looking for a solution to an issue I am facing for a project of mine, relating to tables in HTML. On desktop, the HTML code I have below runs the way I like it to, as the screen is large enough to fit the table within its parent `div`. However, on mobile browsers the parent `div` is less wide, and this has caused the table to over-flow. My table reads vertically as it is a list from highest to lowest, so ideally the content in the second (and following) columns would be placed like an extension of the first column on browsers with low width. So this code...

```html
<div class="parent-class">
<table>
<tr class="row-one">
<td>Item 1</td>
<td>Item 4</td>
<td>Item 7</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-two">
<td>Item 2</td>
<td>Item 5</td>
<td>Item 8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-three">
<td>Item 3</td>
<td>Item 6</td>
<td>Item 9</td>
</table>
</div>
```

...reads this this:

```
|--------------------------|
| Item 1 | Item 4 | Item 7 |
|--------------------------|
| Item 2 | Item 5 | Item 8 |
|--------------------------|
| Item 3 | Item 6 | Item 9 |
|--------------------------|
```

However on smaller browsers, the second and third columns over-flow and produce a horizontal scroll bar on the parent `div` which is not ideal. In addition, having a vertical table with multiple columns is probably poor practice for mobile (my actual table is considerably longer). So to maximise readability and not lose any content, I'd like the table to read like this on mobile:

```
|--------|
| Item 1 |
|--------|
| Item 2 |
|--------|
| Item 3 |
|--------|
| Item 4 |
|--------|
| Item 5 |
|--------|
| Item 6 |
|--------|
| Item 7 |
|--------|
| Item 8 |
|--------|
| Item 9 |
|--------|
```

And finally, if possible, I'd prefer that this 'rearrangement' of the table be done using CSS only, without modifying the HTML or introducing JavaScript. I understand this may be poor practice, but I would like to know if it is possible first of all before I decide how I will fix my issue.

I've looked into using `@media` and selecting relevant cells using `tr:nth-child(n)` but have not been able to find a solution that, in effect, allows me to relocate the relevant cells as described. Is there a solution in CSS at all? Should I look into JavaScript as an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope, no can do. You can re-order elements with flexbox, but they should have a common direct parent. So yes, javascript would be your only solution, as it entails DOM modification

Comment: _“...reads this this:”_ - that looks pretty much as if it wasn’t actual tabular data in the first place, so this should probably be a simple _list_ instead of a table to begin with.

Comment: The data in the table I gave is massively simplified, and is much more exhaustive in my actual project -- I left it out in this post so as not to messy the layout. But I was told below that using a table is outdated irrespective of that, so I'll definitely take that into consideration going forward, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change tables to divs/sections and use this sollution.

**@EDIT**

```css
.parent-class {
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 200px;
float: left;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.row p {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent-class">

 <section class="row">
 
  <p>Item1</p>
  <p>Item2</p>
  <p>Item3</p>
  
 </section>
 
 <section class="row">
 
  <p>Item4</p>
  <p>Item5</p>
  <p>Item6</p>
  
 </section>
 
 <section class="row">
 
  <p>Item7</p>
  <p>Item8</p>
  <p>Item9</p>
  
 </section>
 
</section>
```

Additionaly you can use media queries to positioning element inside .parent-class, but this code doesn't use this method.

Comment: I did mention in the OP that I'd prefer not to modify the HTML, though if a solution is available that way I'll have a look at it. Though, I am unsure how this particular change resolves the issue? I can see how this would allow each `section` to follow the previous one when the browser width is constrained, but this wouldn't produce the ordering from 1-9 I'm looking for. Unless I'm mistaken, it would instead order 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9. Is there some other solution available, or have I not understood?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to change your code you have wrong thinking about elements positioning. Additionaly websites now don't need tables - it is old and wrong way. I was edited my answer, look at this. Run code in full page and try to resize your browser.

Comment: Fair enough -- I'm still learning so I appreciate the clarification. Thanks for the updated response.